# Try to run Python 3.4.3 but still shows Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I installed Python 3.4.3 and then installed Python 2.7.9 on Mac Air. If I run Python on a command line, it shows Python 2.7.9. I removed Python 2.7.9, it still shows Python 2.7.9. What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try the `python3` command.

Comment: Apple computers are distributed with a MacPort of Python 2.

Comment: Python 2 is part of Mac OS X, don't remove it. Use `python3` instead or the full path to the Python 3 binaries.

Comment: Thanks. Just found python3 when installing matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the links are not working

To solve this, backup your current python link:

`cp /usr/bin/python ~/Desktop`

Remove the old soft link and create a new soft link pointing to Python 3.4.3 installation:

`rm -f /usr/bin/python`

`ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python`